# Get Address when map move

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i can't get address when dragend map (but work if dragend marker)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function(event) {
 myMarker.setPosition(this.getCenter()); // set marker position to map center

 updatePosition(this.getCenter().lat(), this.getCenter().lng());
```

JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/turq2myw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass co-ordinate in map drag to get the address like this event does not contain the latlng

```
geocoder.geocode({
       'latLng': this.center
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        var alamat = results[0].formatted_address; 
            document.getElementById("alamat").value = alamat;
     // alert(alamat);
      }
    }
  });
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/turq2myw/1/)

Comment: works like a charm.. thanks! , can i add input type="text" for search address for center map ?

Comment: @Edofx didn't get you can you explain?

Comment: check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bt4dmu1f/ , at search box , can type address , if found , map centered at address.

Comment: you mean getting co-ordinates from address and centering map right ?

Comment: check my scripts, maybe wrong http://jsfiddle.net/ga2dkbku/1 . get error at console locateAddress is not defined . something wrong?

Comment: your fiddle doesn't run there are errors moreover there is no locateAddress in code

Comment: no , jst check my scripts .. im using cordova for get location lat/lon

Comment: make sure locateAddress  function is included in your code

Comment: already include at scripts when  var onSuccess = function(position) called

Comment: not sure why the click event is not recognizing the scope then you just have to bind the click event of locate button to locateAddress function